# Putting a php shortcode in an echo function

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how I would put a PHP function in an echo statement or an alternative for it as shown below.

```
 <?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
    $i = 0;
    $featuredPostNumber = 4; 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $i++;
        if($i==$featuredPostNumber){
            echo '<a href="#"><div class="post-tweet"><h3><?php echo do_shortcode('[get_tweet_timeline username="crearegroup" number="3" showlinks="true" newwindow="true" nofollow="true" avatar="true"]'); ?></h3></div></a>' ;   
        }

        else{
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
        }
        endwhile;

    endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: String Concatenation http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate the values:

```
echo 'Some part of a string' .
    do_shortcode(//function call
        '[get_tweet_timeline username="crearegroup" number="3" showlinks="true" newwindow="true" nofollow="true" avatar="true"]'
    ) . '</h3></div></a>' ; //rest of the string
```

[cf the manual, look for the *"concatenation operator"*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), it's easy

`echo` is a language construct, so it's more efficient to use, but in some cases, you might want to use [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) (and other functions like `sprintf` or `vsprintf`):

```
printf(
    'Some part of a string %s Rest of the string',
    do_shortcode(
        '[get_tweet_timeline username="crearegroup" number="3" showlinks="true" newwindow="true" nofollow="true" avatar="true"]'
    )
);
```

That enables you to keep your code looking nicer than all that tedious concatenating of stirngs.

Yet another alternative would be to mix in markup and php:

```
<a><div><h3><?php echo do_shortcode('[get_tweet_timeline username="crearegroup" number="3" showlinks="true" newwindow="true" nofollow="true" avatar="true"]'); ?> </h3></div></a>
```

Which is equally valid